# Redirect to List Columns

Tags: custom-list

I created new custom list, and I created a new webpart using this list. The list has title, picture, link columns. I want to, when I click the picture it redirect to link.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the webpart Out of the box list view webpart?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean. But it can be very easily done, by inserting a "Promoted Links" web-part. You can add title, picture and a link easily, and a description to appear in the greay area when you hover over the link. Hope this is what you were looking for.
[image: Promoted Links]